# MySQL - get COUNT depends on the value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the COUNT() of the specific field depends on the value of the field? For example I have the field `typeOfAssistance` , in the query below I got the total numbers of the `typeOfAssistance` but I have different values in it which is `financial` `medical` and `burial`, How can I add custom column that will divide the total value depends on the value?

```
SELECT date,COUNT(*) AS num
FROM requests
WHERE date BETWEEN  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -20 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY date
```

desired output:

```
date       | financial | burial | medical | total

2014-04-25 | 1         | 2      | 3       | 6
```

Thanks. Sorry for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically for something like that I would use `SUM` rather than `COUNT` for the item breakdowns.

Something like

```
SELECT  date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfAssistance = 'financial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS financial,
        SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfAssistance = 'burial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS burial,
        SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfAssistance = 'medical' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS medical, 
        COUNT(1) AS Total
FROM    requests
GROUP BY    date
```

Comment: thanks astander and alex for editting. :) It works. :)